# Git keeps having altered files with <EF><BB><BF>

Tags: git

So git keeps complaining that certain files have been edited, when I do git diff on it, it says the entire file has been changed, but it has these characters at the begining . You can see a copy of the terminal from below:

```
$ git diff
index c479381..d9ab8ca 100644
--- a/Assets/Scripts/ScriptableObjects/GameEvent.cs
+++ b/Assets/Scripts/ScriptableObjects/GameEvent.cs
@@ -1,31 +1,31 @@
-<EF><BB><BF>using System.Collections.Generic;
-using UnityEngine;
...
```

The weird thing is I cannot revert these files, git reset --hard HEAD has zero effect, I cannot check out old ones. So my only solution is I must keep committing files which this happens to.

I've run out of ideas on what this is. I don't think it is a line endings issue, it is something else. Has anyone encountered anything like this?

Comment: That's the [Unicode BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098326/ef-bb-bf-at-the-beginning-of-json-files-created-in-visual-studio).

Comment: Most likely it isn't git that's adding the BOM to your files, it's your file editor. Revert is a separate issue, and though there is a git revert command, that'd only work if the file hadn't been saved with a BOM in the previous commit, and there had been no other changes.